# how to select matching row and match its ID and Date on the same table

Tags: sql, transactions, row, matching

I have the following sample data

```
id   dt  a
1    1   token 
1    1   stuff 
1    2   at
2    1   token
2    1   stuff 
2    1   store
3    1   token
3    2   stuff
4    1   stuff
4    1   at
```

I want to return every row with "token" as well as any matching by id and dt observations. the expected output is following

```
 id   dt  a
1    1   token 
1    1   stuff 
2    1   token
2    1   stuff 
2    1   store
3    1   token
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM stuff AS a JOIN
stuff AS b ON (a.id=b.id AND a.dt=b.dt)
WHERE a.a="token";
```

but it just changes the values in a to "token" what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the table against itself to get the result you want. For example:

```
select a.*
from stuff a
join stuff b on b.id = a.id and b.dt = a.dt 
where b.a = 'token'
```

I now realize your solution was almost correct. You filtered the wrong table. That's it.

Comment: thank you very much!! makes total sense and very optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think `exists` does what you want:

```
select s.*
from stuff s
where s.a = 'token' or
      exists (select 1 from stuff s2 where s2.id = s.id and s2.dt = s.dt and s2.a = 'token');
```

Comment: it works! thank you! the only issue is that it goes through a lot of data, I am running it in bigquery and need it more optimized. Ill keep this method in mind!